# Where to get a complete list of FxCop warnings sorted by code?

Tags: fxcop

I'm familiar with the [MSDN list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429379%28VS.80%29.aspx), but I would like to have a list sorted by code. A lot of our developers don't have easy internet access, and it would be nice if I could give them a off-line complete list of the warnings.

I would like them sorted by warning code, because that is how they identify the issues in the Fxcop logfile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an improved, sorted list on MSDN now. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264925.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Glad to see that Microsoft actually fixes these issues.